# Regex for matching a string of positive non-zero doubles seperated by the "$" character

Tags: java, regex, string, number-formatting

**Context**: I have found a solution for matching three Integers seperated by the "$" character as seen below:

```
String toMatch = "123$53$12"; //Returns true
String toMatch2 = "123$0$12"; //Returns false
String toMatch3 = "0$53$12";  //Returns false
String toMatch4 = "123$53$0"; //Returns false
System.out.println(toMatch.matches("\\d+.*\\d+.*\\d+") && !toMatch.matches([^0-9]*0[^0-9]*"));
```

**Problem**: What I want to achieve is:

```
String toMatch = "123.43$.03$123.0"; //Returns true
String toMatch2 = "123$000000$12";   //Returns false
String toMatch3 = "0.0000$53$12";    //Returns false
String toMatch4 = "123$53$.000";     //Returns false
```

Essentially what I want is a Regex matching 3 numbers separated by the "$" character, with each number being a positive non-zero double if parsed by the `Double.parseDouble()` method.

Comment: why `123$000000$12` should not match?

Comment: Because the number 0 is contained within the String.

Comment: I just found a semi-solution and I will update the main post. It's not the solution I am seeking though.

Comment: so if i can understand your String should look like this `ints point ints dollar point ints dollar ints point ints` ?

Comment: The regex should only return true if it looks like `((optional) ints (optional) point (optional) ints)(at least one of the previous) dollar ((optional) ints (optional) point (optional) ints)(at least one of the previous) dollar ((optional) ints (optional) point (optional) ints)(at least one of the previous)`

Comment: Try `"\\d+\\.\\d+\\$\\d+\\.\\d+\\$\\d+\\.\\d+"`

Comment: This is what I have came up with `"("+Pattern.quote("$")+"?\\d*\\.?\\d*"+Pattern.quote("$")+"?){4}"` but this matches an empty String or occurances more than 4 times or the dot on its own.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your solution demands 0.3 for example, I want to accept ".3" as well as "0." and "0" but not ".".

Comment: @AlexPapageorgiou I can't follow you. Do you want or not to accept 0? You have to ask questions more precisely.

Comment: Replace each \\d+\\. with \\d*\\.? in that pattern above. `"\\d*\\.?\\d+\\$\\d*\\.?\\d+\\$\\d*\\.?\\d+"`

Comment: @horcrux Sorry but I am not entirely sure how to explain regexes correctly as it is something new to me and English isn't my native language. I do not want to accept 0 as a number, not as a character. Meaning  I do not accept any substring that can be parsed into the character 0 by the Double.parseDouble() method.

Comment: @horcrux Reworded my initial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've correctly understood, I think this will work:

```
^(?!\\$)((^|\\$)(?=[^$]*[1-9])(\\d+(\\.\\d*)?|(\\.\\d*)?\\d+)){3}$
```

Follows an explenation:

- `^(?!\\$)`: the begin of the match must not be followed by a '$'
- `{3}`: the following pattern has to be repeated 3 times

  - `(^|\\$)`: the pattern starts or with the begin of the string or with a '$' (not both, for what stated above)
  - `(?=[^$]*[1-9])`: before the next eventual '$' there must be a non-0 digit
  - `(\\d+(\\.\\d*)?|(\\.\\d*)?\\d+)`: the allowed format for the number is either `\d+(\.\d*)?` or `(\.\d*)?\d+`
- `$`: end

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/kzBrdd/2) for a demo

An extended expression (if you don't trust the repeat trick) is:

```
^(?=[^$]*[1-9])(\\d+(\\.\\d*)?|(\\.\\d*)?\\d+)\\$(?=[^$]*[1-9])(\\d+(\\.\\d*)?|(\\.\\d*)?\\d+)\\$(?=[^$]*[1-9])(\\d+(\\.\\d*)?|(\\.\\d*)?\\d+)$
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot @horcrux this is exactly what I was looking for. The part I couldn't figure out how to write was the "before the eventual '$' there must be a non-0 digit". Bonus points for breaking it down for me!